# Double unlock needed with kde

Tags: kde, lock-screen, unlock

I installed kde plasma desktop on my Ubuntu 14.04. The problem is that whenever the screen is locked, i have to type my password twice to unlock the session: once in the unity ubuntu and once in the kde. What can I do?